# Intranet logical architecture in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, design, architecture, intranet

So, I am building a Intranet portal. I got my Physical architecture build thanks to tips from stackexchange users.

Now i got som other thoughts. What is a preferred logical architecture for a Intranet that is used for communicaation in the business, show the organization, and have a reporting system consisting of some .net applications.

My idea was to use three WebApplications

1. Intranet
2. MySites
3. Reporting (.net applications)

But now I am a bit confused, would it be better to have the Intranet and the reporting system on a single WebApp and use Host-Named-Sites or should i go with my first idea and use path-based sites and seperate WebApplications.

[Host-Named-Sites](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=255239)
[Path-Based-Sites](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=255238)

Thanks :)

Comment: This diagram will answer all of your questions, http://zoom.it/NO01#full

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember there was a debate I was reading on somewhere on whether to create Host Named sites within a single web application and use the same site for My Sites.

Microsoft [recommends using a single web application](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc424952.aspx#section1a) and then use host named site collections. I believe you can create setup My sites and reporting services within same web application as well.

[image]

Comment: Again, thanks Muhammad :). I will take a deeper look into the host-named-sites, I have never worked with them before, and at the moment I am more confident in the logic of path-based, but maybe the host-named is the way.

Comment: Yes, that's because, path-based are easier to implement and involve less steps to configure ;)